# determine how the user logged in

Tags: linux, logs, users, login

I want to know how the user logged in( Using RDP, ssh, VNC, or any kind of...).
How can I log a general way that is independent of Linux OS shows the type of user's login?

Comment: Have you looked at logs where login attempts (successful and unsuccessful) are logged? How is authentication handled on your system? What Linux system are you using and what VNC server etc. are you running?

Answer (score 0):

`lsof` is a command line tool to determine which files are being used by users and as **everything is a file** in Linux this can be used to see which users are using "ssh" or "xvnc" (which means how they are connected to the server.

here is the CLI code for ssh:

```
% sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '\<ssh\>'
ssh  19749  user  3u  IPv4 148088244   TCP x.x.x.x:39689->y.y.y.y:22 (ESTABLISHED)
ssh  19749  user  4u  IPv6 148088282   TCP [::1]:9090 (LISTEN)
ssh  19749  user  5u  IPv4 148088283   TCP 127.0.0.1:9090 (LISTEN)
```

for vnc/rdp connections these commands can be used:

```
$ sudo lsof  -b -w -n -c /^Xvnc$/b -a -iTCP:5900-5999 
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Xvnc    1625 guest    1u  IPv4 252910      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5910 (LISTEN)
Xvnc    1625 guest    9u  IPv4 261226      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5910->127.0.0.1:35242 (ESTABLISHED)
```

take a look at [Detecting a disconnected RDP session in a unix system](https://gist.github.com/OllieJones/27592fb5660a446dccff092a0c029d11)

Comment: Thanks, but it has some problems, first of all for RDP it just returns the user that listens to the RDP port, not the user that logged in to the server for example in my case it returns xrdp and I want to know who connected immediately that it does not do this.

Comment: will `ps` command help? use `ps -ef | grep Xorg` for rdp and `ps -ef | grep xvnc` for vnc

Comment: As I said it just shows when calling it. but I want to be aware of when users connected, like fire events.